# Getting error while importing tree component along with chips autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to import **tree** component along with **chips autocomplete** componnet, I am getting this

`ERROR Error: Could not find a tree control for the tree.` 
Here i am messing up with use of 2 component's constructors, means i am able to use only one constructor at the time.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-vytgy6?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *ERROR Error: Could not find a tree control for the tree* shows up because the tree control you defined is empty.

As you correctly pointed out you can only have one constructor implementation per component. What you can do is to merge the contents of the two constructors from the material example components into one like so:

```
constructor(private database: LoadmoreDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable, this.getChildren);

    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<LoadmoreFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);

    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

    database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });

    database.initialize();

    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
  }
```

Now the tree control and everything else which is necessary for the angular material tree to work gets set up properly.

Here is the modified [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-qqicsg) with a working tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have a saved my day.